# Remove wordpress session after login

Tags: php, wordpress

When i logged in in my wordpress site i see via firebug inspector that i have some sessions.

```
wordpress_fds6234hfdsf734ythgfg
wordpress_logged_in_fdfds74326uyfd67
icwp-wpsf
wordpress_test_cookie
NID
```

i want to remove:

```
wordpress_fds6234hfdsf734ythgfg
```

which has a path:

```
/wp-admin
```

how can i remove this session once i logged in or how can i avoid create this session? is there any ideas or ways to make it happen? i dont need only to remove it, is enough for me even if i change it to something else.

I want to make it dynamically of course because every time the session value is different!

Comment: `unset($_SESSION['wordpress_fds6234hfdsf734ythgfg']);`

Comment: i updated my post..i want to make it dynamically..and where i have to write this code? in which file?

Answer (score 0):

This code in a custom plugin should do it:

```
function unset_login_undesired_session() {
    unset($_SESSION['wordpress_fds6234hfdsf734ythgfg']); 
}
add_action('wp_login', 'unset_login_undesired_session');
```

Comment: i also created a plugin under plugins folder but no results

Comment: Maybe your code is being executed too early. Try `add_action('wp_login', 'unset_login_undesired_session', 99);` to make it executed later and tell here the result :)

Comment: Try adding `setcookie("wordpress_fds6234hfdsf734ythgfg", "", time()-3600);` after the unset.

Answer (score 0):

To remove your cookie dynamically, you can try using `preg_grep` in conjunction with `array_column`:

```
if( $found = preg_grep( '/^wordpress_((?!_)\w)+$/', array_keys( $COOKIE ) ) )
{
    unset( $COOKIE[current($found)] );
}
```

Above I use the pattern `/^wordpress_((?!_)\w)+$/` that match any `$COOKIE` key starting with *wordpress_* and followed by more than one word charachers (excluding undersore): if you know that key name to delete has **always** 21 characters after *wordpress_*, I suggest to replace above pattern with `/^wordpress_((?!_)\w){21}$/`.

**Please note that Wordpress doesn't use $_SESSION,** so you have to check/set the `$COOKIE` array.

How to place the command? You have to create a simple [plugin](http://wpninjas.com/how-to-create-a-simple-wordpress-plugin/) and to add an action to appropriate wp task.

A good start could be to try with `init`:

```
add_action('init', function() {

    // Your code to match / delete cookie here

});
```

---

- Read more about [preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)
- Read more about [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
- Read more about [How to Write a Basic WordPress Plugin](http://hardcorewp.com/2012/how-to-write-a-basic-wordpress-plugin/)
- Read more about [Wordpress Action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)